# YUI Compressor to compress all the files in a directory

Tags: yui-compressor

I have a js folder that contains `n` number of javascript files (I might add/remove some files from that folder)

can I do something like that?

`java -jar yuicompressor.jar dev/js/* -o dev/js/main.min.js`

I want to merge all the files in that directory into a minified `main.min.js` but the command is not working. (if I put a file name instead of the * it works)